# php echo button and allow all characters for form

Tags: php

How should I echo buttons in php? Nothing happened when I tried to click the button.. or is it I need to do function for it?

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Create new account" onClick="Registration.php(-1);return true;">';
```

Also, how do I allow all characters to be accepted in a form? Cause now,
though form can be submitted but It won't appear anything if my feedback contains ' (Eg, It's nice being here) but it works fine without it (Eg, Its nice being here).. I think is the sql statement is affecting it..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback (Feedback)
        VALUES ('$feedback' )";
```

Comment: are you trying to redirect the user to `Registration.php`? when clicking the button? if so, why not just use an anchor?

Answer (score 2):

You are using javascript to redirect the user. Just giving `Registration.php(-1)` will not redirect.

Try using `anchor link`. This is the best way to achieve it.

Or else if you still want to use javascript, try the below line in your onclick method

```
window.location = "Registration.php";
```

For your sql query problem, you should use `addslashes()` to the values.

```
$feedback = addslashes($feedback);
$sql      = "INSERT INTO feedback (Feedback)
               VALUES ('$feedback' )";
```

Try this and see..

Answer (score 1):

The most important issue you are facing is that your query goes wrong on the `'` character. This means that you are executing your query unescaped.

I would like to recommand using `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysqli_real_escape_string` or even googling `PDO` and `prepared statements`.

It can also be solved using the `addslashes` function as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback (Feedback) VALUES ('".addslashes($feedback)."')";
```

Concerning your button issue:

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="Registration.php">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Create new account">';
echo '</form>';
```